# Batch process parameters

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I have created a form which is called from a class which implements runbase batch, so I have got a batch tab on the form.

When I include the job for the batch process, it does not use the current batch parameters, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the call to `super()` in the `getFromDialog`, `pack` or `unpack` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Write one line in main method as mention below

```
If(batchjobClassName.prompt())
{
    call your run method here
}
```

Hope it helps.